# Deployment to JBoss Wildfly failed after adding Vaadin add-on

Tags: java, jboss, vaadin7

When I add to my pom.xml Vaadin Excel Exporter,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.vaadin.addons</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-excel-exporter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.7</version>
</dependency>
```

I can't run my application via JBoss Wildfly. Without this add-on everything is working properly.
I'm using Vaadin 7.7.13 and JBoss 11.0.0.Final.
Server log (main points):

```
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 10) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."webapp-SNAPSHOT#WebappPersistenceUnit": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."webapp-SNAPSHOT#WebappPersistenceUnit": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: WebappPersistenceUnit] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory

Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: WebappPersistenceUnit] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory

Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.collection.OneToManyPersister

Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to parse order-by fragment

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: antlr.CommonToken cannot be cast to antlr.Token
```

Can anybody help me, how to solve it?

Comment: There is probably a conflict between `antlr` versions. For example, [`vaadin-excel-exporter`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.vaadin.addons/vaadin-excel-exporter/1.0.7) depends on [`pojobuilder`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.karneim/pojobuilder/2.3.3), which in turn depends o [`antlr ST4`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.antlr/ST4/4.0.7), but without seeing the whole `pom` it's difficult to say what to exclude, or what versions to update. You can try running `mvn dependency:tree` to see exactly what depends on what.

Comment: I'm using also hibernate-entitymanager 5.1.10.Final and inside of hibernate-core is antlr 2.7.7. What should I exclude or what should I update?

Comment: You could try to exclude `pojobuilder` from the add-on, and add an explicit dependency in your pom for `pojobuilder 4.2.0` which seems that no longer depends on `antlr`. I downloaded the [vaadin-excel-exporter sources](https://github.com/bonprix/vaadin-excel-exporter), updated to 4.2.0 and ran the demo without any issues, but I don't have your environment so you'll need to check on your end that nothing breaks after this change.